# Get Group Layer children

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, group-layer

I'm new to arcgis javscript api, and trying to get layers from a group layer. I'm not sure how to get this done. any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use esri.request to retrieve information about a service.
For example:
http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Demographics/USA_1990-2000_Population_Change/MapServer?f=pjson
the response is (an extract):
.
.
"copyrightText": "Copyright:© 2013 ESRI",
 "supportsDynamicLayers": false,
 "layers": [
  {
   "id": 0,
   "name": "USA 1990-2000 Population Change",
   "parentLayerId": -1,
   "defaultVisibility": true,
   "subLayerIds": [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4
   ],
   "minScale": 0,
   "maxScale": 0
  },
  {
   "id": 1,
   "name": "Block Groups",
   "parentLayerId": 0,
   "defaultVisibility": true,
   "subLayerIds": null,
   "minScale": 150000,
   "maxScale": 0
  },
  {
   "id": 2,
   "name": "Tracts",
   "parentLayerId": 0,
   "defaultVisibility": true,
   "subLayerIds": null,
   "minScale": 750000,
   "maxScale": 150001
  },
  {
   "id": 3,
   "name": "Counties",
   "parentLayerId": 0,
   "defaultVisibility": true,
   "subLayerIds": null,
   "minScale": 25000000,
   "maxScale": 750001
  },
  {
   "id": 4,
   "name": "States",
   "parentLayerId": 0,
   "defaultVisibility": true,
   "subLayerIds": null,
   "minScale": 0,
   "maxScale": 25000001
  }
 ]
.
.

the first layer (id: 0) is a grouplayer with subLayerIds 1,2,3,4
The other layers (with id 1,2,3,4) have parentLayerId: 0 (the grouplayer).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, about the service url, should I build it? I mean.. I have a map url which contains the group layers and its children. Is the service something I got from the map url or is it something totally different.

Comment: I found it, but when I try to do an esri.request, it gives me this message :NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied. What's the problem

Comment: You can post the url?

Comment: The url is local, and Thanks, it is working now. I don't know what was the problem, I keep making changes until it works.